# In socket.io, the same event happens 2 times

Tags: node.js, typescript, multithreading, socket.io, fastify

I'm using socket.io nodejs cluster in my project and I can't figure out why the same event goes twice.
I tried various versions of Socket.io, but I still get an error, 2 of the same event can go. Socket version: 2.0.5

**ServerCode**

```
const cluster = require("cluster");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const redisAdapter = require("socket.io-redis");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
const { setupMaster, setupWorker } = require("@socket.io/sticky");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  const httpServer = http.createServer();
  setupMaster(httpServer, {
    loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection", // either "random", "round-robin" or "least-connection"
  });
  httpServer.listen(3000);

  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on("exit", (worker) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);

  const httpServer = http.createServer();
  const io = new Server(httpServer);
  io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: "localhost", port: 6379 }));
  setupWorker(io);

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("connected");
    socket.join("data");
    io.to('data').emit("event", "data");
  });


}
```

**Client Code**

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

socket.on("event", (data) => {
  console.log("Received data:", data);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Usually this problem happens because you have a code path where you set up duplicate listeners for the same event.  Thus you "think" the event is happening twice, but really you are just listening to it twice.  Or it could be because the code that emits the event is somehow getting called twice.  You aren't showing us enough complete code for us to be able to diagnose either of those possibilities.

Comment: Do you realize that your code should show two messages `Received data: data` if you have two clients connected?  So, if you just open two tabs in the browser and then restarted the server, both tabs will reconnect to your server.

Comment: I've added client and server codes, I'm not listening or sending from anywhere else

Comment: If this is ALL the code, then you likely have two clients connected.

Comment: no i only have 1 client and this is not something that happens all the time, it happens sometimes.

Comment: I suspect you sometimes have an extra client sitting in a tab somewhere then.  I don't know how else to explain it.  If you change this `console.log("Received data:", data);` to this `console.log("Received data:", data, socket.id);` it will tell you if it is the same or different client emitting each message.

Comment: same id returns: Connected to server
Received data: data 2i7x0H8SoiYXdNcNAAAB
Received data: data 2i7x0H8SoiYXdNcNAAAB

Comment: Then your code must have duplicate listeners or you're sending duplicate messages.  You have at least ruled out duplicate clients present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed when I downgraded the socket.io version and socket.io client to the old version.

Answer (score -1):

```
io.to('data').emit("event", "data");
```

Replace that line in your server code with:

```
socket.emit("event", "data");
```

Or:

```
io.in('data').emit("event", "data");
```

What the former code was doing was that it was emitting the "event" event to the client as soon as the server was created and the client connects to it, and since the client is already listening for the "event" event, it will receive it twice.

Comment: Huhhh?  I don't understand what you're saying.  The OP's code is trying to do `.emit("event", "data");` to ALL clients in the `data` room including the one that just connected.

Comment: If he wanted to emit event to all clients in the data room including the one that joined, then he would be using the io.in("data").emit() method.

Comment: I don't think they want `socket.to()` because that sends to all sockets in that room EXCEPT the `socket` one and they only have one client and it appears they are expecting to see the received message once.

Comment: FYI, `.in()` and `.to()` appear to be the same thing in this context.  See [code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/main/lib/namespace.ts#L254) and [code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/main/lib/broadcast-operator.ts#L70).

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm afraid not in this context. If they wanted to use the `io.to()` method specifically, it shouldn't be within the `io.on("connection")` code block, unless they wanted to send a private message. In that case, the parameter in the `io.to()` method would be the socket ID. See the socket.io cheatsheet [here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet)

Comment: I can see where the error you are pointing out is, and I'm going to update my answer to reflect that. Here, the OP would be better off with the basic emit `socket.emit()`, or `io.in("data").emit()`, but not `io.to("data").emit()` in this context.

Comment: this doesn't work because I'm clustering so there are two out of ten. if you get the code and run it you will understand.

Comment: Best bet would be to move the `io.to('data').emit("event", "data")` out of the `io.on("connection")` block or place it in a callback in the socket.on() method like this `socket.on("connect", () => io.to('data').emit("event", "data"))`. With this, the event would only be emitted once no matter the number of workers you have on. I was really trying to help though, no idea why I was downvoted. Good luck.